# Laravel print object into html table

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have this kind structured object

```
{
 - NewYorkCity: [

   -{
    Men:100
},
   -{
    Women: 100
},
 ],
  - Boston: [

   -{
    Men:120
},
   -{
    Women: 180


}
```

I just want to print those inline, like this:

```
NewyorkCity   |    100     |   100
Boston        |    120     |   180
```

I tried this code:

```
 @foreach($cities as $key => $val)
            <tr>
                <td> {{$key}}</td>
                <td>{{$val[1]}}</td>
            </tr>
    @endforeach
```

In this situation, $key (city names ) prints without problem.
men and women counts not. it gives error "Array to string conversion "

How can i fix it? 
Thanks.

Comment: `$val` is an associative array right, so `$val["Men"]` or `$val["Women"]` should work.

Comment: how can i use digit instead of Men and Women, is it possible?

Comment: Use an indexed array instead. But how are you going to distinguishe male and female than? Just by knowing that the first entry in the array is male would not be a good idea.

Comment: i changed it indexed array, then try to get $val[1] still same error, array to string conversation...

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What if your code changes in the future and you would have to provide more information than male and female. How are you going to know the difference between the given values? Just by knowing the order is not a good idea. Edit your question to show the changes you made to index the array.

Answer (score 1):

If you would want your array to be indexable you should change your data accordingly e.g.

```
array(
  NewYorkCity => array(
                   100,
                   100
                 )
);
```

Than you could use `$val[0]` and `$val[1]` in your blade foreach loop, but i would not do this, since than there is no clarification what these values stand for. If you would have to provide more data in the future it gets even more messy, so just use `$val["Men"]` or `$val["Women"]`.

Comment: this is the vardump of my array: array(2) { ["NewYorkCity"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["Men"]=> float(200) } [1]=> array(1) { ["Women"]=> float(245) } } ["Boston"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["Men"]=> float(505) } [1]=> array(1) { ["Women"]=> float(100) } } }

Comment: Cmon, now you've made each entry an array itself. Than it is obvious why it does not work. Now you would have to do `$val[0]["Men"]` and `$val[1]["Women"]` , but there is no need to do that. You should read about arrays http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: $this->data[$city->name][]  = [ $sex->name => $total];  i am doing this in eloquent's each.. am i creating array wrong?

Comment: [$sex->name => $total] part  creates an array for every sex, but i want to collect it in one array.. how can i do it?

Comment: `$this->data[$city->name] = [ $sex->name => $total];` , but are you sure you need to do this? Can't you just use the eloquent result an loop over that?

Comment: i am selecting sum for each city from cities table ( nested code ) so at the end of code, i have to collect all data according to citiy and send to blade...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78890/discussion-between-yigitozmen-and-daviddomain).

Answer (score 0):

```
Try $val['Men'] and $val['Women']
```

Comment: how can i use digit instead of Men and Women, is it possible?

Comment: it is possible, if you setup your object to use arrays instead of objects in an array.